# How to shared common resource theme for Universal 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have WP 8.1 app and now I am converting that to Universal 8.1 App, but what I found that the styles/resources like "PhoneForegroundColor" which is used in Phone 8.1 but not available on Windows desktop 8.1, so what should be the better approach? Shall I create a new resource style and than copy each of unavialble resources from WP Generic.xaml.
After searching a bit I found [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-xaml-and-ui) article, which has list of all the keys that are not supported in Universal App.

Comment: Have you tried my suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the missing resources in the Generic.XAML page and this will point each resource to the new one, or you can simply replace the old resources by the new ones using the Visual Studio find and replace (Ctrl+F)..

I prefer the second way since you're upgrading the full project..